# Use spring mvc xml project inside spring-boot project

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, gradle, spring-boot

I have this test project I created, composed out of 2 projects: one using spring-boot and one using spring-mvc. Each one of them works fine standalone.
What I want to do is to run the spring-boot and be able to access the web pages of the spring-mvc project by loading its context.
The project is quite simple as I just want to test how to do the mix.

The problem is that when I am running the spring-boot application, the page from spring-mvc is not accessible, as it does not add the webbapp folder (containing WEB-INF) in the build.
I am able to autowire the service from spring-mvc inside the spring-boot application.

The tree looks as follows:

[image]

The Application.java class for spring-boot is the following:

```
package hello;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;

import java.util.Arrays;

@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan({"org.burdu", "hello"})
//@ImportResource({"classpath:WEB-INF/spring-core-config.xml", "classpath:WEB-INF/spring-mvc-config.xml"})
public class Application {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    ApplicationContext ctx = SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);

    System.out.println("Let's inspect the beans provided by Spring Boot:");

    String[] beanNames = ctx.getBeanDefinitionNames();
    Arrays.sort(beanNames);
    for (String beanName : beanNames) {
    System.out.println(beanName);
    }
}
}
```

The root build.gradle

```
group 'net.burdu'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'idea'

sourceCompatibility = 1.8

repositories {
mavenCentral()
mavenLocal()
}

dependencies {
testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.11'
}
```

root settings.gradle

```
rootProject.name = 'testSpringXMLAndBoot'
include 'spring-mvc'
include 'spring-boot'
```

spring-boot build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'idea'
apply plugin: 'war'
apply plugin: 'spring-boot'

sourceCompatibility = 1.8

repositories {
jcenter()
mavenCentral()
}

buildscript {
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:1.3.3.RELEASE")
}
}

dependencies {
compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web")
compile project(':spring-mvc')
}
```

spring-mvc build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'idea'
apply plugin: 'war'
apply plugin: 'jetty'

sourceCompatibility = 1.8

repositories {
mavenCentral()
mavenLocal()
}

dependencies {
compile 'ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:1.1.3'
compile 'org.springframework:spring-webmvc:4.1.6.RELEASE'
compile 'javax.servlet:jstl:1.2'
}

jettyRun{
contextPath = ""
httpPort = 8080
}

jettyRunWar{
contextPath = ""
httpPort = 8080
}
```

spring-core-config.xml

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
   xsi:schemaLocation="
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd ">

<context:component-scan base-package="org.burdu.web" />

<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="viewClass" value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView"/>
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/view/" />
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
</bean>

<mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />

<mvc:annotation-driven />

</beans>
```

spring-mvc-config.xml

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
   xsi:schemaLocation="
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd ">

<context:component-scan base-package="org.burdu.service" />

</beans>
```

web.xml inside spring-mvc project

```
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
    http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
     version="2.5">

<display-name>Gradle + Spring MVC Hello World + XML</display-name>
<description>Spring MVC web application</description>

<!-- For web context -->
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>hello-dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
    </servlet-class>
    <init-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring-mvc-config.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>hello-dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<!-- For root context -->
<listener>
    <listener-class>
    org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
    </listener-class>
</listener>

<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring-core-config.xml</param-value>
</context-param>

</web-app>
```

The HelloController inside spring-boot, HelloWorldService and WelcomeController are simple beans. I am not pasting their content here since the question already got too long, but if needed I can add them.

Comment: I guess there must be some more configurations needed. Could you please publish your projects to github or just mail it to me? I'm going to do some more research about it and publish any useful information if I've achieved.

Comment: https://github.com/Burdu/testSpringXMLAndBoot

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've imported the combined projects into my IDE and I found it's hard to integrate two projects into one and keep them original. The real difficulty is spring could not known the resources inside jar of sub-project `spring-mvc` located in `lib/spring-mvc.jar`. If I extract it into sub-project `spring-boot`, it still doesn't work.

Afterwards, I found this documentation about [`JSP limitations`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-customizing-configurableembeddedservletcontainerfactory-directly) in spring-boot, which says:

> An executable jar will not work because of a hard coded file pattern in Tomcat

What's more, my suggest is to convert your application into modern spring-boot form as following:

> [Convert an existing application to Spring Boot](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-traditional-deployment.html#howto-convert-an-existing-application-to-spring-boot)

In this case, you just need convert your servlets and filters defined in `web.xml` into spring beans as documentation said. Additionally, `spring-core-config.xml` and `spring-mvc-config.xml` can keep no change cause they can be imported directly even though they are in embeded jar. It should be easy.

After you converting your application into spring boot, you can take all control over the web container too.

At the end, if you are really want to use them together, following documentation could be useful:

> [Deploying a WAR in an Old (Servlet 2.5) Container](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-traditional-deployment.html#howto-servlet-2-5)

This time, you can specify `SpringBootContextLoaderListener` as your listener at your `web.xml`. It could help to configure your application. However, as what spring says, it's only useful for deploying your application into old container.

But, if I were you, I will convert it to spring-boot format. Cause it can simplify maintenance work.

By default, spring boot only allowed directories `/`,`META-INF/resources`,`resources`,`public`,`static` as resources loading path. From this prospective, if all your resources are located under these directories it should work. Of course, [specifying document root](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.4.0.M2/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-customizing-configurableembeddedservletcontainerfactory-directly) would be required. If you can tolerant extracting `spring-mvc`, I think this would be the solution.

If **spring context defined in embedded jar** is what you want, you can just add a star after `classpath` such as `classpath*:WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml`. This will add any `WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml` in any lib jar. In other words, you only need add a star after `classpath` at your `@ImportResource` expression. If all things' going well, you are there.

Comment: Thanks. You can drop the jsp part. Imagine that the spring-mvc application is only REST and in webapp you have javascript frontend. Would that be doable?

Comment: I'd tried to extracting `spring-mvc` into `spring-boot`, which made it as part of `spring-boot`(If you kept `spring-mvc` as a embeded jar, `File` could not recognize resources in `spring-mvc`). Afterwards, I'd debugged `spring-boot`, I found it only allowed directories `/`,`META-INF/resources`,`resources`,`public`,`static` as resources loading path.

Comment: I've improved my answer at the end, please have a look!

Comment: What if your project does not have a web.xml, and it is only a subproject for persistence for example? It only has the applicationContext.xml. So we would have spring-mvc, spring-boot and spring-persistance. I know this was not in the main question, but I did not think it would come down to web.xml.

Comment: My point is that if you donnot need to keep mvc pages as you've defined, to integrate it to boot could be very easy. For example, you just want controllers to be integrated, the only work is add the package into ComponentScan. Is only controllers defined in mvc what you are care about?Not the static pages? Do I get your point?

Comment: I am referring to something else. Nevermind the pages, the spring-mvc package. Imagine a different package spring-persistance with only persistence beans. Yes, I add the package into component scan, but doesn't it need the context.xml where the beans are declared? Does it see it if it is in a different package (no web.xml in it). I would like to do this with minimum changes done to existing code.

Comment: That should just be a bit work. But I'm going to bed now, a little late already. I'll give my explanation about 8 hours later. So sorry for that, too tired.

Comment: If you just need to integrate spring context defined in embedded jar, you need add a star after `classpath` such as `classpath*:WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml`. This will add any `WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml` in any lib jar. You only need add a star after `classpath` at your `@ImportResource` expression. If all things' going well, you are there.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/110377/discussion-between-gemini-keith-and-burdu).

Answer (score 2):

I tried these small changes to your [github project](https://github.com/Burdu/testSpringXMLAndBoot):

spring-boot/build.gradle:

```
// This will include files and settings from spring-mvc
war {
    baseName = 'testSpringXMLAndBoot'
    version =  '0.1.0'
    from '../spring-mvc/src/main/webapp'
}

// tomcat-embed-jasper is for jsp support
dependencies {
    ..
    compile("org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-jasper")
    ..
}
```

spring-boot/src/main/java/hello/Application.java:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan({"org.burdu", "hello"})
@ImportResource({"classpath:WEB-INF/spring-mvc-config.xml"}) // added this resource back
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ApplicationContext ctx = SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
        ..
    }
}
```

Now running:

- spring-mvc/gradle jettyRun

Will still run standalone `spring-mvc`module on Jetty server

And running:

- spring-boot/java -jar build/libs/testSpringXMLAndBoot-0.1.0.war

Will include `spring-mvc` context to `spring-boot`and run them on an embedded Tomcat.

Comment: but you still can't run it using the Application.main inside spring boot

Comment: Can you clarify what that means? How are you running it?

Comment: I mean you can run spring applications from your IDE by simply running the Application.main class. In the alternative you provided, you are not able to do that.